# Consistency of surrogate key for config tables in different environments

Tags: database, postgresql, key, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

We have several config tables that represent jobs to be run (in Airflow). We have a dev, test, stage and prod environment and have multiple teams working in these environments at different paces. For example, one team may start in dev before another team but may deploy to test after.

Teams create entries in the config table in dev with autoincrementing ids and the the ids are used as foreign keys as well to connect the config tables to fully represent each job. The issue is that the INSERT statements into the config tables are added to code and then deployed to other environments but the ids may have to be different in different environments if another team has already used the same ID in another environment. This results in the foreign keys in the INSERT statement not being reliable. How is this situation typically handled?

Comment: Any specific reason you use surrogate keys and not descriptive text strings? Why are you storing your configs in a database and not in files under source control? What does Redshift have to do with this setup, is your database Redshift or PostgreSQL?

Comment: As @Quassnoi suggested having descriptive text keys might be a right way to go. It it is not plausible in your work flow - using GUID keys instead of autoinc integer might be a solution. You would not have to autogenerate a key in different configurations data bases - have it be the same on all of them.